# MySql/phpmyadmin query not working - unrecognized keyword 'NOT'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Trying to write a query to add the string 'No' to every field that's "late" column doesn't have the value 'Yes', but phpmyadmin is telling me there is an unrecognized keyword immediately after I type the keyword 'NOT'. Why would this be? The query I'm using is:

```
UPDATE pubs SET late = 'No' WHERE late NOT LIKE '%Yes%'
```

Comment: Your syntax looks correct.

Comment: Thanks. Bug will be tracked here: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11646. Note that you can submit your query and it will work.

Comment: please add the error

Comment: what happens with -> UPDATE pubs SET late = 'No' WHERE late NOT LIKE 'Yes%'

Comment: @davejal this is a bug in phpmyadmin and you can still enter the query and it will work, as I did.